# Weakening of GCD: maximal common divisor (MCD)

Tags: ring-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, monoid

I'm dealing with integral domains and have come across the following weakening of the notion of a GCD (which I will write analogously as MCD): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_common_divisor

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $A\subset R$. The following statements are formulated up to associatedness.

It's pretty obvious that

1. if the GCD of $A$ exists, it's also an, and the only, MCD of $A$.

I'm wondering if the converse is also true:

2. If there is exactly one MCD of $A$, it is the GCD of $A$.

Or is there a counterexample with, for instance, two divisibility chains of common divisors of $A$ starting from $1$ such that one of them has finite length (terminating in the MCD) while the other has infinite length? So in order to find a counterexample, $R$ must necessarily violate the ACCP, right?

Comment: Please check this, this provides the example you need. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#In_commutative_rings

Comment: Doesn't every element of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ have a finite number of divisors? Therefore, if there is exactly one MCD, it is the GCD.

Comment: No. Having a finite number of divisors DOES NOT IMPLY there is exactly one MCD.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking for. Let me state it again: Provided there is exactly one MCD (for a given subset), is it also the GCD (for that subset)?

Comment: What you are talking about is just an example for my first statement formulated as a contraposition: If there is not exactly one MCD, there is no GCD.

Comment: Ok... I am sorry I misunderstood the problem.